# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'DateTimeProperty'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination, cursor, data-modeling

I am using Google App Engine with python 2.7 and try to reproduce the example given at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-paging-python/blob/master/suggest_cursor.py to use paging with cursor inside my page (see https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/paging)

datamodel.py

```
class Feedback(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    subject = db.StringProperty()
    text = db.TextProperty(default='')
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

My code looks quiet similiar but I get errors:

1)

```
query = datamodel.Feedback.all().order(-datamodel.Feedback.created)
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'DateTimeProperty'
```

2) with removed - query = datamodel.Feedback.all().order(datamodel.Feedback.created) the result is this error

```
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2614, in order
    if property.startswith('-'):
AttributeError: 'DateTimeProperty' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Any idea why this won't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndb` and `db` are completely different modules; you can't use ndb example code and expect it to work in db.

You need to give the property name, quoted, to the `.order()` call:

```
query = datamodel.Feedback.all().order('-created')
```

Comment: ah thanks, as there was no datamodel I did not recognized that the examples were ndb based. Didn't even know about ndb! thx